# For every $A \subseteq X$, $A = \bigcap\{U\subseteq X: U \text{ is open and } A \subseteq U\}$

Tags: general-topology

I found this question [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/notes/05-sequences.pdf). However, I have no idea how to approach this question. The question asks us to prove the equivalence of these four statements.

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Prove that the following are equivalent.

> - $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$

> - For every $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is closed

> - Every finite subset of $x$ is closed

> - For every $A \subseteq X$, $$A = \bigcap_{\substack{U\in \mathcal T\\U\supseteq A}}U$$

I showed the equivalence of (1) and (2). (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3) follows immediately since every finite set can be given as the union of singletons. However I am unable to show the equivalence of (1) and (4).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's enough to show $(2)\iff(3)$  (which is straightforward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in A$, then obviously $x$ belongs to all open sets containing $A$. Conversely, if $x\notin A$, then for every $a\in A$, there are some open neighbourhoods $U_a$ of $a$, such that $x\notin U_a$. Put the union of all $U_a$'s as $U_0$, then $U_0$ is an open set containing $A$, and $x\notin U_0$. Therefore $x\in U_0^c$. Hence $A^c$ is contained in the union of all complements of open sets containing $A$, which implies that the intersection of all opens sets containing $A$ is contained in $A$.

Conversely, if (4) holds and $x,y$ are disjoint points, then $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all its open neighbourhoods. Hence there must be at least one neighbourhood not containing $y$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution but I am unable to do so. Can you elaborate a bit? You proved in the first stanza that $$\bigcap_{A\subseteq U} U \subseteq A$$ whereas yuo needed to prove that they are equal. Where's the other inclusion?

Comment: @Ryukendo Dey The basic idea is to prove $A^c\subset\cup U^c$. To prove this, let $x$ be disjoint from $A$, then there is a neighbourhood of $A$ disjoint from $x$. Hence every $x$ disjoint from $A$ belongs to some $U^c$ . The converse is trivial, since every point belongs to $A$ also belongs to sets containing $A$.

Comment: I thought we needed to show that the sets $\bigcap_{A\subseteq U} U$ and $A$ are equal

Comment: Also, where did you use the fact that the space is $T_1$?

Comment: @Ryukendo Dey For every $a$ belongs to $A$, there are some neighbourhoods of $a$ disjoint from $x$.